# How to keep my test methods with proguard.cfg

Tags: android, proguard

For my Android instrumentation test I need a few extra entry point into my classes. Those methods are not used in the actual application. My idea was to start them all with `test_` and have a general rule to exclude them from being optimized away. This is how far I got:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.xxx.**.* {
    public ** test_* ();
    public ** test_* (**);
    public static ** test_* ();
    public static ** test_* (**);
}
```

But it still does not work. `public static void test_destroy (final android.content.Context context)` and `private void dropTables (final SQLiteDatabase db)` has just been removed from the code. And I have no idea why.

How is it properly used for wildcard patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is

```
-keepclassmembers class com.XXX.**.* {
    *** test_* (...);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to use an annotation (i.e. guava's @VisibleForTesting) to mark those methods. Then in proguard you can keep all entry points and members with that annotation:

```
-keep @com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting class *

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
  @com.google.common.annotations.VisibleForTesting *;
}
```

Comment: Note that you have to be careful that the @VisibleForTesting annotation that you use is available in the .class file. android.support.annotations.VisibleForTesting, for example, has a RetentionPolicy of SOURCE, so it won't be kept and thus can't be used by proguard.